# Null Column gets listed in list command when using Pandas

Tags: pandas

When I create a DataFrame from the CSV shown below and list the columns, I get the following :

rpai@rpai-wsl:~/projects/weight$ cat data/weight.csv

```
Days,Date,Beer,Bad,Gym ,Push,Pull,Core,Wt,Comment, 
1,15-Mon-Oct,No,No,No,0,0,No,79.6, ,

['Days', 'Date', 'Beer', 'Bad', 'Gym ', 'Push', 'Pull', 'Core', 'Wt', 'Comment', ' ']
```

It creates the last column with " " and I can remove it by using :
`del df[' ']`

Question 
a) Why do we have the column " " in the first place?

Comment: try removing comma from the end of each line in your csv.

Comment: for .csv files comma means there one more parameter at its right.

Comment: could you add the code and dataframe generating the csv?

Comment: Yes. Removing the leading comma fixes the problem. Thanks.